# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I want request-response with wsdl in php
But I getting error

"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized"

***WSDL***  https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsarizi?wsdl

**My code in index.php**

```
$istek = new SoapClient('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsarizi?wsdl');

$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->Username = '999999';
$auth->Password = '999999testtest';
$header = new SoapHeader('https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetdsarizi?wsdl', 'AuthHeader', $auth, false);
$istek->__setSoapHeaders($header);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($istek->__getTypes());
echo "</pre>";

echo "<hr /><br /><br /><br />";

$sonuc = $istek->seyahatIzinKontrol(array(
    'wsuser' => array(
        'kullaniciAdi' => '999999',
        'sifre' => '999999testtest')
    ,
    'tcKimlikNo' => '15058023598')
);

if ($sonuc->seyahatIzinKontrol) {
    echo 'OK';
}else {
    echo 'ERROR';
};
```

**Here is the error I'm getting:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:72 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://servis....', 'http://uetds.un...', 1, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(72): SoapClient->__call('seyahatIzinKont...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 72
```

What my error?

Comment: I use PHP 5.2.0

Comment: https://uetds.uab.gov.tr/uploads/pages/teknik-dokuman/uetds-arizi-yolcu-tasimaciligi-kurum-entegrasyonu-teknik-tasarim-dokumani-v12-62e7b52d1b95e.pdf

Comment: Pls write code for php

Comment: some reference PHP for Using a SOAP Web Service https://answers.sap.com/questions/11543698/using-a-soap-web-service-php.html